# MySQL NOT IN return a wrong number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to clean a database with a lot of orphaned entries, on this case i have a table 3 tables

- 'Email' (69529 entries)
- 'ServiceHasEmail' (5782 entries)
- 'UserHasEmail' (26254 entries)

The two last tables reference the 'Email' table, so this table should have 26254 + 5782 (32036) entries.

I built a query to select all the entries on the 'Email' table which are not referenced on the UserHasEmail and ServiceHasEmail tables:

```
SELECT * FROM Email e 
WHERE e.EML_Id NOT IN (SELECT EML_Id FROM ServiceHasEmail) 
   AND e.EML_Id NOT IN (SELECT EML_Id FROM UserHasEmail)
```

But this query returns me 40383 entries in place of 37493 (69529 - (26254 + 5782))

What i am missing here?

Comment: Maybe some emails appear in both tables

Comment: Are you sure some email addresses don't appear in both ServiceHasEmail and UserHasEmail? That would result in more rows than your expected amount.

Comment: I guess 2890 EML_id are in ServiceHasEmail AND in UserHasEmail: Try SELECT count(*) FROM ServiceHasEmail INNER JOIN UserHasEmail ON ServiceHasEmail.EML_Id=UserHasEmail.EML_Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be because

- tables ServiceHasEmail and UserHasEmail contains some emails
  both.
- tables ServiceHasEmail and UserHasEmail contains duplicates.

You can verify:

```
select count(distinct email) from Email 

select count(distinct email) from ServiceHasEmail

select count(distinct email) from UserHasEmail
```

and

```
select count(distinct Email) 
from
(select Email from ServiceHasEmail
 union all
 select Email from UserHasEmail
)
```

And your query should be

```
SELECT count(distinct Email) 
FROM Email e 
WHERE e.EML_Id NOT IN (SELECT EML_Id FROM ServiceHasEmail) 
   AND e.EML_Id NOT IN (SELECT EML_Id FROM UserHasEmail)
```

Comment: It could also be due to `NULL` values, since `NULL` won't evaluate `TRUE` when compared to a `NOT IN`.

Comment: Thanks! for some reasons, some EML_Id indexes were duplicated in the ServiceHasEmail table although they shouldn't be. Looks like it will be more complicated than i expected to clean this database...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some ServiceHasEmail and UserHasEmail reference the same Email.

Answer (score 0):

You could have `EML_Id`'s, that are present both in `ServiceHasEmail` and `UserHasEmail`.

I suppose you have exactely 2,890 of them. Please try

```
SELECT * FROM `ServiceHasEmail` INNER JOIN `UserHasEmail` USING(`EML_Id`)
```

to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following query:

SELECT * FROM Email e 
WHERE e.EML_Id NOT IN (SELECT EML_Id FROM ServiceHasEmail UNION SELECT EML_Id FROM UserHasEmail)